# how to get full yaml file form running azure AKS

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I tried to pull yaml from my running AKS, which kubectl options I can run in order to pull full yaml file form running azure AKS , need it for only 1 AKS Name ?

full yaml file means - the same as if I go on azure portal and click and go inside of my AKS, then on the left pane I can click:  "export template" , but it is in json, I need the same in yaml

Comment: Can you please specify what was meant by "full yaml file form running azure AKS"? Do you want the AKS cluster's profile in yaml format or do you want specific Kubernetes resource(s) running on the AKS cluster in a yaml format?

Answer (score 2):

In the following answer I have referenced [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/what-is-azure-cli) commands. You can find installation instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli).

If you want the [`managedCluster`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managed-clusters) object of an AKS cluster in yaml format please run:

```
az aks show -g $ResourceGroupName -n $AKSClusterName -o yaml
```

If you want specific [Kubernetes resource(s)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/) in a yaml format

- First run

  ```
  az aks get-credentials -g $ResourceGroupName -n $AKSClusterName
  ```

  to  get the access credentials for the AKS cluster and merge them into the `kubeconfig` file.
- Now you can run:

  ```
   kubectl get $resource-type $resource-name -n $namespace -o yaml
  ```

  Please replace `$resource-type` with the correct Kubernetes resource type (e.g. pod, node, deployment, service, replicaset, ingress etc.) and `$resource-name` with the corresponding desired resource name. If you want to get a list of all resources of `$resource-type` you can ignore specifying `$resource-name`. If you want to list resources of $resource-type in all namespaces please replace `-n $namespace` with `--all-namespaces`

  For example, if you want to get the list of all pods in the namespace development in yaml format then, you should run:

  ```
  kubectl get pods -n development -o yaml
  ```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands